# sqlite3 call with metadata via Python

Tags: python, sqlite

I'd like to perform the following sequence of statements via a single call from Python:

```
> sqlite3 -hexkey thehexkey database_file
sqlite> .hex-rekey thehexkey "" ""
sqlite> .exit
```

How can I cause the meta-commands (.hex-rekey and .exit) to be executed by sqlite3 via a single sqlite3 call from Python? I can make the call to sqlite3, but I don't know how to get the meta-commands to execute unless I do everything from the command line.

Answer (score 0):

The [documentation](http://www.sqlite.org/cli.html) says:

> **Using sqlite3 in a shell script**
>
> One way to use sqlite3 in a shell script is to use "echo" or "cat" to generate a sequence of commands in a file, then invoke sqlite3 while redirecting input from the generated command file. This works fine and is appropriate in many circumstances. But as an added convenience, sqlite3 allows a single SQL command to be entered on the command line as a second argument after the database name. When the sqlite3 program is launched with two arguments, the second argument is passed to the SQLite library for processing, the query results are printed on standard output in list mode, and the program exits. This mechanism is designed to make sqlite3 easy to use in conjunction with programs like "awk". For example:
>
> ```
> $ sqlite3 ex1 'select * from tbl1' |
> >  awk '{printf "<tr><td>%s<td>%s\n",$1,$2 }'
> <tr><td>hello<td>10
> <tr><td>goodbye<td>20
> $
> ```

Comment: Is it possible to accomplish it w/o using awk?

Comment: In this example, `awk` is just used to convert the output.